# Minio too many open files, please increase 'ulimit -n'

Tags: minio

1、when I visit the minio by brower,the log is following.

```
returned an error (too many open files, please increase 'ulimit -n') (*fmt.wrapError)
internal/logger/logonce.go:54:logger.(*logOnceType).logOnceIf()
internal/logger/logonce.go:94:logger.LogOnceIf()
cmd/erasure-metadata-utils.go:139:cmd.readAllFileInfo.func1()
internal/sync/errgroup/errgroup.go:123:errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
```

2、At the same time, the total objects is less than that I have upload.
[the result of my minio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZqSq.png)

in fact,the size of objects is about 150000.
3、the following is my minio file;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvJJH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this error means you exceeded the number of open file descriptors allowed for this process/user. You can check current limits with `ulimit -n` and increase the maximum open fd's with `ulimit -n 65535`

Please know you can find us at https://slack.min.io/ 24/7/365. If you have commercial questions, please reach out to us on hello@min.io or on our Ask an Expert Chat functionality at https://min.io/pricing?action=talk-to-us.